# in Visual studio 2015 the designer change property, like size, of a controls in a win form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015, windows-forms-designer

i have a windows form with a lot of controls like datagrid, panel, groupbox, tab control ecc... In VS2015 every time i open the form in design mode, the designer made some little change at size, point or location properties of some control as shown in the screenshot from the diff of svn.

[screenshot of a diff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdhlR.png)

and i did not change anything only save and re-open in designer. When i do this, the designer also change the position of some block of code.

Usually i work with the *.designer.cs in read only mode, but when i have to make changes to the UI it is not possible to work in this way... so any one knows how to solve this issue?

Thanks a lot

Comment: It's not really much help but we get this all the time - it's happened since VS2012 at least.  Generally when we check form changes into TFS we have to revert random designer changes.

Answer (score 0):

Set Form's [AutoScaleMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.autoscalemode(v=vs.110).aspx) property to `None`.

Or you can use some panels to organize your controls on form, like create a`TableLayoutPanel` and add rows and columns and dock controls in each cell.